# Changing active class in bootstrap navbar but with different ul s

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a (not professional) project to practice my coding skills. I'm using bootstrap for some things, including navbar. But I want to change active class (nav items are in different ul s)

I have tried the basic methods found by just googling "change active class in bootstrap" but my html code is not similar to anyone. I have tried using a unique class name, making active to current, but that breaks the code. So i have to use active class. I appreciate all the help guys, thanks.

https://github.com/Carbonautics/carbonautics.github.io
This is my code on github.com

I want it to change active class based on click, and also based on what the user is viewing ( ex: home as active if user is on homepage, about as active if user scrolls down to about page).

Snippet: https://codepen.io/carbonautics/pen/oKvgWK

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse w-100" id="navLinks">
        <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-center" id="activeLink">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a href="https://carbonautics.github.io" class="nav-link">home</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto w-100 justify-content-end">
            <li class="nav-item hover" id="hoverbtn">
                <a href="#About Me" class="nav-link">about</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item hover">
               <a href="" class="nav-link">progress</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Idk how to use demo and stuff, this my first question sorry, guys.
If you see the codepen, I want home (active) to be in centre, and change class when clicked OR if the user is currently scrolled down to about me page.

Comment: Hi Carbonautics. You'll get better results here if you can set up a quick demo for others to see/interact with rather than pasting a link to a git repo.

Comment: Please provide a small section of your code here also.

Comment: I'm sorry, this was my first time asking for help on stack overflow, idk how this works, but i put a code pen link (first time there as well ). Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using jQuery addClass to add your custom class after a click event?
Something like: `$( "p" ).addClass( "yourClass" );`

Comment: I kind of tried something like that. But I have to remove class from current and add to new class, but they are in different ul , and my second ul has two items, so i can't use ul classes to switch